# InterfaceOrientation deprecated in iOS 8

Tags: ios8, uikit, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

I am not using Size classes in my project and continue to use old methods for view controller orientation. I am getting deprecation warnings, such as when I use code below :

```
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
      ...
    }
```

I have searched a lot but could not find the right way to fix it. Any suggestions ?

Comment: The way to "fix it" is to use the new methods. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: "I am not using Size classes in my project" Well, there's your problem. Orientation-related info is communicated to you through the `traitCollection` as size classes. Obviously if you refuse to look at it, you won't see it.

Comment: How do I translate from UITraitCollection to UIInterfaceOrientation ? Example, which trait collection refers to Landscape left orientation ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since iOS8, Apple recommends to use TraitCollections (Size Classes) instead of interfaceOrientation.

Moreover, since iOS 9 and the new iPad feature "Multitasking", there are some cases where the device orientation doesn't fit with the window proportions ! (This leads to brake your application UI)

However, sometimes TraitCollections doesn't fill all your design needs. For those cases, Apple recommends to compare view's bounds :

```
if view.bounds.size.width > view.bounds.size.height {
    // ...
}
```

I was quite surprised, but you can check on the WWDC 2015 video [Getting Started with Multitasking on iPad in iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-205/) at 21'15.

Comment: But I have a problem with it, it is incapable of distinguishing between landscape left and landscape right. How do I get that?

Comment: You're right @DeepakSharma, however size classes allow you neither to distinguish between landscape left and landscape right. Why do you need this information ?
If you want the device orientation and not the screen orientation, you can use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`

Answer (score 9):

Should change

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
  ...
}
```

to

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: 'statusBarOrientation' was deprecated in iOS 13.0 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965701/statusbarorientation-was-deprecated-in-ios-13-0-when-attempting-to-get-app-ori

Answer (score 0):

Some of you may need to use UIDevice Orientation

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
   ...
}
```

instead of Status Bar Orientation

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: 1. statusBarOrientation - deprecated, 2. Using device orientation is wrong. For example, device can be in portrait but interface - in landscape.